# PHP Convert Date/Time Format to another

Tags: php, date, time

I have a Date/time value as such;

```
2014-01-07T16:19:08Z
```

I wish to convert it to the format below using PHP

```
2015-03-21 02:12:01
```

I know I could use string replace twice over to remove the T and Z characters but doesn't seem right..

Comment: `str_replace(array('T', 'Z'), ' ', $timestr)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `strtotime()` with `date()`

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2014-01-07T16:19:08Z'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The date_format() function returns a date formatted according to the specified format.

```
$date=date_create("2014-01-07T16:19:08Z");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

One more way is there

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2014-01-07T16:19:08Z'));
```

Update

The date_create() function returns a new DateTime object.

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp)**

Comment: Whats is date_create() function do?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2014-01-07T16:19:08Z'));
?>
```